# jquery loaded html div elements selector

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

First sorry if its a stupid question but i ran into a problem what i cant really solve.
I am loading a html file with the `load` function, and my problem is if i load the html file with the `load` function, the selectors with jquery dont really work, only with css.

(i use codeigniter)

example

load the html

```
$('.get_posts').hide().load('stream/load_posts').fadeIn(800);
```

so this html (view) file contains the following

```
<?php if(isset($stream_posts)): ?>
<?php foreach($stream_posts as $sp): ?>
<div id="sp_<?php echo $sp->sid; ?>" class="row stream-posts">
    <div class="span1 stream-thumb">
        <ul class="stream-thumbnails unstyled">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="stream-thumbnail">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div class="span5 stream-content">
        <a href="#" class="author"><?php echo $sp->first_name ." ". $sp->last_name; ?></a>
        <p id="stream-text"> 
            <?php echo nl2br(auto_link($sp->text)); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i use codeigniter so at this line `<?php echo nl2br(auto_link($sp->text)); ?>` Automatically turns URLs and email addresses contained in a string into links, so when i have an auto link i would like to add an oembed class to it, so i tried the following

```
$("p.stream-content a").addClass('oembed');
```

and its not working, tried with css with the same selector with difference by coloring the anchor tags red, in css it works, than i discovered, the jquery selector part its not working because i use load, if i uncomment load and show the results via php it adds the class fine with jquery too.

Could please someone give me a hint for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding the class on the callback of `load()`?

```
$('.get_posts').hide().load('stream/load_posts', function() {
  $("#stream-text a").addClass('oembed');
}).fadeIn(800);
```

Note that I have changed your `$('p.stream-content...` because there is no `<p>` element with `class="stream-content"`

Comment: sorry those where my typos, but thank you works with the callback, thanks so much (will accept your answer have to wait one min)